# Router keep asking for correct password

Tags: windows, router, authentication, internet-explorer-8

When I try to log into our Thomson SpeedTouch router using IE8, I get the following message:

> HTTP/1.0 401 Authorization Required

The prompt act like I've typed a wrong password, but it works fine when using Firefox or Telnet.

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called [Digest Authentication mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)  witch need to be disabled in order to proceed.

for my case, this command under telnet will disable it :

```
system config digestauth=disabled
```

**UPDATE**

Microsoft says IE don't support Digest Authentication

> Internet Explorer does not pass your
>   user name and password automatically
>   when you are using Basic (clear text)
>   authentication or Digest
>   authentication. Therefore, you are
>   always prompted for credentials when
>   you are using these authentication
>   methods. Internet Explorer prompts for
>   a password when you are using
>   anonymous authentication.
>   [source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063)

Comment: -1 This would be a bug with the Router Software, as blank3 pointed out. You should have given him credit for pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Router/Modem software can be buggy. Have you:

- restarted the router,
- cleaned the IE cache and
- retryed logging?

Comment: Uf... sorry for trying.

Comment: He's right, web-based software on network gear is notoriously buggy.  Doesn't matter who makes it.  I had to retire a Cisco router because I didn't have an old enough browser + Java combination to log in to it.  If Firefox works, maybe use it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you the only one experiencing the issue locally?  If not, go to tools, internet options, click on the advanced tab, scroll down about halfway and check that you have the 2 boxes under HTTP 1.1 selected.  Unless you have customized settings in there, you could also just reset all the settings to the default and see if it works.

i would also look at how you are entering the login credentials.  if you are hitting enter after typing your password, try clicking OK instead and see if that works.

Comment: tanks for the reply, found the solution